# Display SPUser Information on an application page

Tags: 2010, application-pages, spuser

I have an application page (SP2010) where I have a SPUser object (the current user), now I would like to display this SPUser as an Hyperlink on the apsx, linked to his UserProfilePage (userdisp.aspx) like those links in a normal list (field Author or Editor). Sure I could make a new hyperlink control and use the attributes (?) of the SPUser object to build something that looks like it could be OOTB from SP - but it isn't.

Is there any "best practice way" or "official MS way" to display these information? Perhaps so that the lync status of the User will be shown too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use [SPFieldUser.GetFieldValueAsHtml method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduser.getfieldvalueashtml.aspx)?

**Update**

You can try use this code, but I'm not sure about details because it from my head and I cannot test it now.

```
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
SPFieldUser userField = SPContext.Current.Web.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.AssignedTo] as SPFieldUser;
string userLookup = string.Format("{0};#{1}", user.ID, user.Name);
string link = userField.GetFieldValueAsHtml(userLookup);
```

Comment: No, this is new too me. Will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Maybe i don't get it - but this will require a list where I read a field, right? I have no list, I have only a SPUser Object (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser). Or maybe someone have an example too share?

Comment: @mr.purzel, see the update section of my answer.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, that will do it for me! Didn't check yet if lync status is shown up beside the user name (lync server isn't installed yet on the SP server), but looks good in the html source. Happy!