# Get lync/skype for business status for SPUser object in list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom, lync

I am writing a core solution for SharePoint 2013 und use CSOM. I have got a SharePoint list which contains a user element. In the list, the Lync/Skype for a business status of the user is displayed without problems.

Now I need the Lync status in my application. I get the SPUser object but did not find a property to get the Lync status from the user.

Is there a way to achieve this with CSOM?

Comment: Similar thread is here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108996/display-spuser-information-on-an-application-page

Comment: In this thread nowhere is mentioned how to get the lync status from a user

Comment: string link = userField.GetFieldValueAsHtml(userLookup); will give you the required HTML i reckon.

Comment: I don't need html but a simple status in my program code like "Online/Away/Offline". This only gets me a html link.